# Where to put @SuppressWarnings in a one-liner involving Runnable lambda as argument?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to figure out how to do

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void run() {
        List list = new LinkedList();
        list.add("some string"); //without
            //`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` javac warns about
            //`[path to file].java: [path to file].java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`
    }
});

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Runnable runnableJava8 = () -> {
    List list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("some string");
};
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(runnableJava8);
```

in one line, e.g.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //where to put this??
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
    List list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("some string");
});
```

which causes `<identifier> expected` as well as putting `@SuppressWarnings` before `()` or the `{}`.

I don't want to fix the code to avoid the warning, I'd like to be able to use `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes")` and others as well. Putting the annotation on the surrounding block/method/class level works, but it has more impact than I want - it's a valid workaround, but no answer to the question.

Comment: The answer depends on your IDE. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Milk It's a compiler warning, so I hardly doubt that. See https://github.com/krichter722/java-suppresswarnings-on-lambda for a MCVE, you can open it in any IDE and will encounter the same compilation failure.

Answer (score 4):

Best option is just to fix the code sl that it does not trigger the warning (just declare

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

If for any reason can't or don't want to do it: In your scenario, you could add the annotation right before the offending local variable declaration:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("some string");
});
```

The only other alternative i can think of is putting the annotation at the surrounding class level (the one all this code is added to). But i would strongly discourage it, you should want to be warned about this kind of warnings in other places of same class.

Comment: Very sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. It's not an XY problem, the `List` code was really just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the warning at higher levels.

Add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before your function or class definition to apply the suppression throughout.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Here
public class NewMain {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Or here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```